# unable to use sharepoint online with sharepoint 2010 workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have created a sharepoint designer 2010 .workflow in sharepoint online and kept a email action to see if the workflow works.but the email are no firing but it seems to be working fine with sharepoint designer 2013.

What could be wrong with it ?

Answer (score 1):

Possible Reasons:

1. User initiating the workflow does not have required permissions. To avoid this, Please run the send email action under "**Impersonation step**" and then publish the workflow
2. Issue may come if particular user's mailbox is not configured properly.
3. Keep an eye on how your designer WF is getting fired? Manual/Itemcreated/Item edited. and try to create an entry in Workflow History List

and Lastly, try to update some field value of current list item by running the action "**Update xxx in current item**". This will ensure that if there is some problem with Workflow OR it lies only while sending email.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could also be because the 'Workflows can use app permissions' is not enabled for the site, maybe?

Comment: Yes, This feature must be activated for a site to use App Step or Impersonation Step in SharePoint Designer 2013